# How to flip image using raphael free transform?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, raphael

I am using RaphaelJS and Raphael-Free-Transform for image manipulation in my project. Here I am trying to flip image horzontally. For this I am changing free transform scale value. Image is fliped, but the image gets displaced from its original position and it also gets restored to its original state so we also lose the flip.

CODE:

```
$scope.flopImage = function () {
if ($scope.currentImage !== null) {
var ft = paper.freeTransform($scope.currentImage);
ft.attrs.scale.x=-ft.attrs.scale.x;
ft.apply();
}
};
```

CASE:2

```
$scope.flopImage = function () {
if ($scope.currentImage !== null) {
var ft = paper.freeTransform($scope.currentImage);
$scope.currentImage.transform("S-1,1");
ft.apply();
}
};
```

NOTE:

```
ft = paper.freeTransform($scope.currentImage,{draw:['bbox'],
             rotate: true,keepRatio:[ 'axisX', 'axisY', 'bboxCorners', 'bboxSides'],range: { rotate: [ -180, 180 ] },
             scale:[ 'axisX', 'axisY', 'bboxCorners', 'bboxSides' ]});
```

Comment: Not tried using angular with it, but would it make more sense to use Raphaels transform string (more like case2), but you would also need to take into account its current transform, so pseudocode like currentImage.transform( currentImage.transform().toTransformString() + 'S-1,1') ?

Comment: @Ian The isuue is I am using keepRatio property of free transform The issue is because of this. Don't know hot to maintain ratio for negative value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:
90 degree Move:

```
 $scope.flopImage = function () {

    if ($scope.currentImage !== null) {

        var ft = paper.freeTransform($scope.currentImage);

        ft.attrs.rotate = ft.attrs.rotate + 90;
        if(ft.attrs.rotate === 360) {
            ft.attrs.rotate = 0;
        }
        ft.apply();

    }
};
```

180 degree:

```
$scope.flipImage = function () {
    if($scope.currentImage !==null){
        var ft = paper.freeTransform($scope.currentImage);
        ft.attrs.rotate = ft.attrs.rotate + 180;
        if(ft.attrs.rotate === 360){
            ft.attrs.rotate=0;
        }
        ft.apply();
      \
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
ft = paper.freeTransform(img, ftConfig.opts, ftConfig.callback),
ft.attrs.scale.x *= -1;
ft.apply();
```

You can analogously do this for the y-axis.  When flipping over the y axis.

As commented in the original question, setting the keepRatio option to true causes problems.  After you apply the negative scale, when you rotate the image, or attempt to resize the image, weird things happen.  To fix this problem, you apply the following hack (it was line 1166 for my version of raphael.free_transform):

```
function keepRatio(axis) {
    return;
    if ( axis === 'x' ) {
        ft.attrs.scale.y = ft.attrs.scale.x / ft.attrs.ratio;
    } else {
        ft.attrs.scale.x = ft.attrs.scale.y * ft.attrs.ratio;
    }
}
```

Specifically, add a return statement to prevent keepRatio from modifying the scale attributes.  This hack will **still maintain the aspect ratio**

Comment: Thanks!  I'm still actively working on my project.  Can I ask how you solved the problem?

Comment: Yes. You can reach me out for any assistance. Reach me @prakashh108@gmail.com